# What am I doing wrong? Rendering takes forever

Tags: rendering, export, .fbx, performance

I am a beginning art student who is trying out Blender for the first time. I made this file for my class, but rendering seems to takes forever. It feels like it should be a rather simple animation, but when I try to export it into FBX, even my school workstation crashes. What can be done to reduce complexity of this animation so it can be properly rendered and exported?

Here is a screenshot: https://we.tl/t-lHCYyVGUbF

Comment: Please take some time to describe your project, is it an animation? How many objects does it have? How many triangles? How many modifiers? Can you post a screenshot? Can you find a way for the question to be searchable in google and useful for others in future? Otherwise it's not a good fit for SE and I'm voting to close it for the time being (if it gets closed, remember you can just fix the question and it will be reopened).

Comment: While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users with similar issues find it.

Answer (score 0):

FBX doesn't export simulations unless you are exporting every vert position in every frame and that is absolutely not optimal. I assume you are trying to export this to a game engine because FBX is 3d model format. If you are using a game engine you have two options:

Do the vfx in the game engine instead. Blender's vfx system cannot transfer into game engines.

Render out your animation and use the video in your game engine: and in the properties panel<Scene<Film<Render click the check box next to Transparent background. I think the QT video codec supports transparent video. This method is not optimal.